# Adapt my old work flow to Backbone

Tags: javascript, mvvm, backbone.js

Im starting to build a new app and I would like to use Backbone as my framework.  Below is a basic workflow that this (and most apps) follow.

What is the correct/best model to use with Backbone?

**Old Way**
User navigates to a page.
Selects "Create New widget"
User is presented with a form filled with inputs
At this point I would probably take the values entered (after passing basic validation), wrap them up and send them to the server via an ajax request
Request comes back as "OK" and the user is taken somewhere else (This step isn't entirely important)

Some basic pseudo-code

```
// Grab values
var userName = $('.UserName').val(),  
    dateOfBirth = $('.DateOfBirth').val();  
  ...  
  ...   
  ...

 $.ajax({
  url: "/Webservices/ProcessStuff",
  success: function(result){
   if (result) { 
    // Render something or doing something else
   } else {
    // Error message
   }
  },
  error: function () { 
    // Error message
  }
});
```

**Backbone way**
Using the same example as above; I assume I'd have a model for the user information and a view to display the inputs. However, processing the actual call to the web service is one of the things I'm confused about. Where does this need to go? In the model or in the view `click` of some "Go" button?

`Model.UserInformation = Backbone.Model.extend({ username: null, dateOfBirth: null });`

Maybe also have a collection of these UserInformation models?
`UserInformations = Backbone.Collection.extend({ model: Model.UserInformation' });`

So bottom line what I'm asking is...
What is the best way to achieve this functionality?
What is the proper way to actually perform CRUD? Where to put the actual call to delete/update/create/etc?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have the right idea and Backbone should make it easy for you to get things done using the same basic high level overview of your workflow. Note that you're still going to be using jQuery for this functionality - you'll just be doing it through the organizational aspects of Backbone's types.

There are a couple of key items that you'll want in place, most of which you already mentioned:

- A backbone View to coordinate the HTML elements with your Javascript code
- A backbone Model to store all of the data that the user input into the HTML elements
- A back-end server that can handle RESTful JSON calls via AJAX requests from jQuery

I think the only thing you are missing is that the model has a `save` method on it, which wraps up all of the logic to call the create / update routes on your back-end server. The model also has a `delete` method to handle deletion from the server.

As a very simple example, here's a form that renders an HTML template to the screen, gathers the user input in to the model and then saves it to the server.

An HTML template:

```
<script id="myTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  First name: <input id="first_name"><br/>
  Last Name: <input id="last_name"><br/>
  <button id="save">Save!</button>
</script>
```

The code to run this:

```
MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: "/myModel"
});

MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: "#myTemplate",

  events: {
    "change #first_name": "setFirstName",
    "change #last_name: "setLastName",
    "click #save": "save"
  },

  initialize: function(){
    _.bindAll(this, "saveSuccess", "saveError");
  },

  setFirstName: function(e){
    var val = $(e.currentTarget).val();
    this.model.set({first_name: val});
  },

  setLastName: function(e){
    var val = $(e.currentTarget).val();
    this.model.set({last_name: val});
  },

  save: function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the button click from posting back to the server
    this.model.save(null, {success: this.saveSuccess, error: this.saveError);
  },

  saveSuccess: function(model, response){
    // do things here after a successful save to the server
  },

  saveError: function(model, response){
    // do things here after a failed save to the server
  },

  render: function(){
    var html = $(this.template).tmpl();
    $(el).html(html);
  }
});

myModel = new MyModel();
myView = new MyView({model: myModel});
myView.render();
$("#someDivOnMyPage").html(myView.el);
```

This will give you a quick start for a form that saves a new model back to the server.

There are a couple of things your server needs to do:

- Return a valid HTTP response code (200 or some other response that says everything was "ok")
- Return the JSON that was sent to the server, including any data that the server assigned to the model such as an `id` field.

It's very important that your server do these things and include an `id` field in the response. Without an `id` field from the server, your model will never be able to update itself when you call `save` again. It will only try to create a new instance on the server again.

Backbone uses the `id` attribute of a model to determine if it should create or update a model when pushing data to the back end. The difference between creating a new model and saving one is only the `id` attribute. You call `save` on the model whether it's a new or an edited model.

A delete works the same way - you just call `destroy` on the model and it does a call back to the server to do the destroy. With some HTML that has a "delete" link or button, you would attach to the click event of that HTML element the same as I've shown for the "Save" button. Then in the callback method for the delete click, you would call `this.model.destroy()` and pass any parameters you want, such as success and error callbacks.

Note that I included a `urlRoot` on the model, as well. This, or a `url` function are needed on a model if the model is not part of a collection. If the model is part of a collection, the collection must specify the `url`.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Does the method `sync()` have anything to do with `save()` or are those mutually exclusive?

Comment: It's related, yes. When you call `save`, it will eventually delegate to the `sync` method. The default is to use the `Backbone.sync` method. You can override this by providing a `sync` method directly in your model definition.

Answer (score 0):

If the "el" of the view is the form tag, then you could probably use the built in event object to bind a function to submit, but if the root of the view is something else, then you'll need to attach the click handler in the render function.